# How to fix "ERROR: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container." in android studio 3.5

Tags: google-play, build.gradle, android-studio-3.5

I am trying to build and android project from an imported android source code; but each time I try building, I get this >> "ERROR: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container". How do I fix it

I recently converted my Web Application to a Native android app via goNative.io; of which it built an apk I can install on my phone and the android source code. on building the project in my android studio, I get the error >> "ERROR: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container". The bug was traced to my build.gradle. Here is what it looks like

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I expected a "Build Successful" message so that I can upgrade my API Level to 28 the rebuild back to apk so that I can finally publish on google play store.
Please help fellas

Answer (score 61):

set gradle-wrapper.properties file to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

or higher

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: I had to read all stuff above, to come to something with +18 that will work. This happens when people do not accept answers.

Comment: The true answer. Usually encounter this when I am going manage old projects

Comment: This resolves the issue but in my case, it requires gradle-6.5-bin.zip

Comment: You can find the exact gradle version by going to `build.gradle` -> under `dependencies` ```classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:<grade-leversion>'```

Comment: work for me. should be marked as answer

Answer (score 10):

[image]    only add this line of code in build.gradle(module:app) file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
         maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I already fixed this problem a long time ago

Answer (score 5):

This solution working for me to replace google() tag with.

```
maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is sometimes generated **when you try to run a project created using an older version of Flutter** than the one you're currently using.

Causes
When a project is created with flutter create foo several files in the ios/ and android/ sub-directories are created.

Newer Flutter versions might generate these files a bit differently and projects created with older Flutter versions might cause issues.

to fix:

Supposing that your project is in c:\root_of_your_project\name_of_your_project

Delete the ios/ and android/ directories and go to root directory of your project with CMD, and:

c:\root_of_your_project\flutter create -a kotlin name_of_your_project

and

c:\root_of_your_project\flutter create -i swift name_of_your_project

Answer (score -4):

You get this error if a `google()` dependency is not wrapped in a `repositories` block, so if you do something like this:

```
allprojects {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

Should be:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```