# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'user-auth-retrofit'

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, build.gradle, retrofit2

I am using "auth-retrofit" and that problem I face it,
and I can't understand where is the problem and why that's my Gradle code and that's the shown error.

```
"" Build file 'C:\Users\Ammar\AndroidStudioProjects\user-auth-retrofit\build.gradle' line: 7
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'user-auth-retrofit'.Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.""
```

[image]

here's my Build gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "ERROR: Could not find method google() for arguments \[\] on repository container." in android studio 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755725/how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-method-google-for-arguments-on-repository)

Comment: I tried for sure but does not work too

Comment: cool, just wanted to make sure you've seen that and tried it

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to upgrade gradle version?

Comment: What is the value of distributionUrl in `gradle-wrapper.properties`?

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip

Comment: I tried to change it according to many answers here ,but with no solution too

Comment: Try to invalidate cache and restart

Comment: I tried to upgrade the Gradle version and  the value of distribution and  invalidate cache and restart with no solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227275/discussion-between-ammar-yasser-and-bek).